# Data from Sheet one into Sheet two

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

[image]

In image, i have data in sheet 1 and want specific data in sheet 2

Comment: `XLOOKUP` to get the _Name_ from the _Emp ID_, `SUMIFS` to get the _Value_ from the _Emp ID_ and _Salary Type_.

Comment: Don't think `XLOOKUP` was available for excel-2007 @DarrenBartrup-Cook, `VLOOKUP` should do it still. (sumifs is fine, checked to be sure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the formulas as shown in the picture below:

For Name

> =VLOOKUP(F2,A2:B13,2,0)

For Basic HRA and Special allowance -

> =SUMIFS($D$2:$D$13,$A$2:$A$13,$F$2,$B$2:$B$13,$G$2,$C$2:$C$13,H$1)

fill across
[image]